# My button is not displayed on my chatbot rasa tested over rasa x

Tags: button, chatbot, rasa-nlu, rasa-core, rasa

I had included some buttons on my rasa chatbot and if you click on that button, it gives me the read sign that I can not access content. like it is shown on image below:

[image]

My domain is the next :

[image]

[image]

Comment: If you turn on debug mode, does it show that the correct action is getting predicted?

Comment: @Melinda how can I do this? from rasa x?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After several trials I got the response!
Well I could not got the possibility to click on any button because in my stories I had defined two successive utter_response :

- utter_givesinfo
- utter_moreinfo

means I will not give the user the chance to choose any button so after deleting:

- utter_moreinfo

I resolved the problem well as it is shown on the next figure:

[image]